# how can i edit instance of the Project class in the Django shell after i created

Tags: python, django, django-models

i created an entry in my projects table and saved it to the database with django shell but i want to customize my entry after i created what should i do ?

```
>>> p1 = Project(
...     title='My FirstProject',
...     description='Another web development project.',
...     technology='Flask',
...     image='img/project1.png'
... )
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Project(
...     title='My Second Project',
...     description='A final development project.',
...     technology='Django',
...     image='img/project2.png'
... )
>>> p2.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get first object that you created in the given example, you need to retrieve that object first by doing the following (if you don't know the id)

```
p1 = Project.objects.get(title='My FirstProject', description='Another web development project.', technology='Flask', image='img/project1.png')
```

If you know the id then simply do this

```
p1 = Project.objects.get(id=1)
```

and then do whatever you want to do like updating the title:

```
p1.title = 'My First Project'
p1.save()
```

Comment: thanks first i get  eror :NameError: name 'Project' is not defined than i solved it with typing from projects.models import Project after that your answer worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Then, first of all, you have to get that `Project` by `id` and change it as below...

```
proj_obj = Project.objects.get(id=1)
proj_obj.title = `new_title`
proj.obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly `update()` objects without retrieving them:

```
Project.objects.filter(title='My FirstProject').update(title='My edited first project')
```

Note: This would update multiple projects with the same title. You can also filter by `id` if you know the `id`. Since the `id` is unique this would only update one project.